# Braintree & Magento 2.2 Client Tokens

Tags: magento2, api, braintree, token

Please forgive my ignorance. I've been successfully building & managing Magento 1 stores for a few years and I usually manage to muddle my way through server configurations & installs with little errors.

I decided to try my hand at Magento 2 and have found it to be all new levels of complicated. I've installed, designed and launched a new Magento store, all payment methods are working except for Braintree. I have signed up for an account, had it approved, followed guides to enter API keys etc but I'm getting Payment errors. I used developer tools to track it down to an error 400 Bad Request.

I spoke to Braintree who have passed me back to the Magento community. They can see that my site is communicating with Braintree but when passing the client token back to Magento, the software is not handling it. His exact words were "Magento is not handling the client SDK token or there is no valid SDK link"

Client tokens etc are double dutch to me and I never had any issues like this with Magento 1.9! Are there any guides etc I can follow that may point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of magento 2 are you using? You can take look at this tutorial https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-braintree-payment-method-magento-2.html . Possible you might have issue with credentials.

Comment: Hi, it's Magento 2.2.2 I'm using - That was the guide I initially followed. I waited until my account was activated from Braintree then used the API credentials provided.

Comment: I should also note that the Braintree support tech said that the transactions are not even getting to the point where the Dynamic Descriptors would cause a problem